# Doctrine of SQL get state from log table

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I can't come up with how to retrieve certain data from my sql.
I am working with symfony3 and doctrine. But an SQL will do too.

```
Game
- id
- hometeam
- awayteam

Player
- id
- team

GameAction
- id
- game
- player
- action

Action
- id
- name
```

2 of the Actions in the Actions-Table are 'gets on ice' and 'gets off ice'

I want to find out which players are currently 'on ice'. I am looking for all those players which had an 'gets on ice'-event with no following 'gets off ice' event in this game.

How would such a query look like?

Any hint much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One general approach is to compare counts for each action:

```
SELECT player
FROM GameAction ga
JOIN Action a on ga.action = a.id
GROUP BY player
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN a.name = 'gets on ice' THEN 1 END) > COUNT(CASE WHEN a.name = 'gets off ice' THEN 1 END)
```

This would display only players who have more instances of 'gets on ice' than 'gets off ice', and accounts for these actions happening multiple times per player.

Note: Not really sure these are the correct columns for your join/select, it's hard to tell without sample data, but you can join to the other tables and add other columns to the select and group by as needed (`game`, `team`)